# I have a function detecting collision between 2 divs. How do I execute a new function when the collision result is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

edit: To put it simply, I can detect when frogger gets run over by a car, but I am unsure how to use that result to run the next function to hide frogger.

I am making a simple game of Frogger for a class assignment and so far I have managed to get the collision detection working between 2 divs. My question now is, when the collision function is true, how do I use that to run a second function, like hiding the player.

```
function collision($frogger, $car1) {
  var x1 = $frogger.offset().left;
  var y1 = $frogger.offset().top;
  var h1 = $frogger.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $frogger.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $car1.offset().left;
  var y2 = $car1.offset().top;
  var h2 = $car1.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $car1.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}
 function handleCollisions() {
    if (collision($('#frogger'), $('#car1'))) {
       $('#frogger').hide; // hide player onCollision
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is a method in jQuery not a property.

```
 $('#frogger').hide();
```

Comment: Am I on the right track here? I am still learning and your answer although appreciated hasn't helped me much with what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setInterval () method.
`enter setInterval(code,millisec) here`
Whether or not the collision has been detected by the overlap of positions.